# image popup (DIV) for jQuery that loads large image on demand

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've tried dozens of image zooming jQuery plug-ins, but don't want all the fancy loading effects due to me wanting to show hundreds of thumbnails on a page (which, with every jQuery plugin out there for image zooming, requires either the large images loading or both thumbs and large images loading on the page), which would take a 2-3 minutes to load all the underlying large images.
All I need is an example of a simple script that, when the mouse is hovering over the thumbnail, a popup (DIV tag, that it) shows the large image (which is loaded ON-DEMAND).  When the mouse moves away from the large image, it disappears/closes.

[website showing example of exactly what I'm trying to do](http://www.icarpetiles.com/p/Autumn-Harvest-Shimmering-Blue__TL-AutumnHarvest-ShimmeringBlue.aspx?catpg=discount-carpet-tiles-mini-lots-blues.aspx&pagenm=0)

The site link above basically shows exactly what I'd like to do (the example is not using jQuery, but some over bloated 3rd party control).

What I plan on having is a grid showing up to a few hundred thumbnails, so the on-demand is an absolute must - no need for fancy animations.

I plan to use the latest version of jQuery-UI

How might I go about this? Are there any on-demand image popup plugins for jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hover event in jQuery. To create an div to load the large image when mouse move in and destroy the div when mouse move out. Here is a simple example(the smallImage will have an "bigImageSrc" attribute to hold the source of large image):

```
$(".smallImage").hover(function(){
    //move in function
    var bigImage = $("<div></div>").appendTo(".bigDiv");
    $("<img></img>").attr("src",$(this).attr("bigImageSrc")).appendTo(bigImage);
    $(this).data("bigImage",bigImage);
}, function(){
    //move out function
    var bigImage = $(this).data("bigImage");
    bigImage.remove();
    $(this).data("bigImage",null);
});
```